# Dynamically creating objects and clicking one of the objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

*I asked another version of this question on the gamedev.SE site earlier today but figured I could get better answers here. Also reformulated the question some. I hope this is okay couldn't find anything prohibiting it in the FAQ*

I'm playing around with making a puzzle game, haven't done that much before I run into my first problem.

**Question a)** Basically, I want to create a certain amount of the same object/function (a ball). But the objects will be created dynamically (since the amount of balls could range from 3 to 25), preferably with a for loop pushing the different balls to an array.

However I'm not experienced enough to figure out a good way to do this.

Also, once I have my array of balls on the canvas, I want to be able to select one of the balls.

**Question b)** How do I know/determine which ball in the array was clicked?
Is a simple for loop enough and accessing the objects with [i]?

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hustlerinc/GnxYy/2/) example of what I want with 1 ball (you need to click the orange ball to select, then you can move it around by clicking anywhere on the canvas).

This is what I want to do, but with more balls, and the amount of balls is not specified (deciding the amount part i got covered). How could I solve this in a easy way?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a for loop is fine for your object generation.

As for detecting when you click an object in the canvas, [this tutorial](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful)  might help. It appears there is no built-in feature for tracking objects in your canvas - you simply do manual hit detection based on the common pixels under your mouse and object

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Paper.js has great DOM model, and out of the box ability to click and select items

http://paperjs.org/tutorials/project-items/transforming-items/

hit testing:

http://paperjs.org/examples/hit-testing/

Comment: I don't want to use external libraries, that doesn't teach me anything. And the clicking part I got covered. I need to know how to do this on a bigger scale.

Comment: a library is not a black box , you can still read the source code.

Comment: Yes but most of the time it has a couple of 1000 lines of code. That makes it difficult to get the pieces you need without putting down a month of your life. Reverse engineering is not my strong side.